# Is it safe to reuse RSA, EVP_PKEY, etc. structs?

Tags: openssl

Given an openssl function like

```
int RSA_private_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from,
 unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
```

it seems PROBABLE that "unsigned char *from" is actually "const unsigned char *from".

But how about the RSA?  Is there any documentation other than the source code to tell whether this and similar functions may modify the RSA passed in?

Is it safe to use the same RSA to call RSA_private_decrypt again passing the same RSA?

Reading source code to determine this seems fraught - it shows whether the version I am looking at is safe, but since the API makes no claims of const, he behavior could be changed at any time.

Comment: I believe OpenSSL is doing a better job at const-ness nowadays. What version of the library are you using?

Comment: My application is using 1.0.2.  But the API is the same in 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the "from" argument is declared as const in both OpenSSL 1.1.0 and 1.0.2 but there is a bug in the documentation. I just raised a PR to fix it:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/2899

RSA is definitely *not* const. It may be modified (e.g. for blinding purposes).

Yes you may use the same RSA object in a subsequent call.

Comment: And the above PR is now in git so the docs will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: If RSA may be modified, how can you conclude that it is safe to reuse it? Also, in the question there is EVP_PKEY.

Comment: The modifications are mainly due to caching certain values for blinding. The actual key values and parameters are unchanged. The RSA object is designed for reuse. The EVP_PKEY is also intended for reuse.